# Datagridview auto refresh incompleted

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Data insert in to sql is keep changing in datagrid display. But its not appearing fully. example i have got four column in this table. While run first time its displaying 4 columns data. But while i inserting the data in to table then two column data only its coming.

Column1,Column 4 is not appearing in datagridview while button click .
please note that. Column 1(ID) auto-increment  and Column(time) is autotimestamp.
my sql code is

```html
USE [d]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [no] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [time] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

my vb code is

```html
        protected void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=PC;Initial Catalog=d;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            String st = "INSERT INTO data(no,name,time)values (@no, @name, GETDATE())"; 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", textBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox6.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            con.Close();
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";
    
            dataBindingSource5.DataSource = dataTableAdapter.GetData();
             dataBindingSource5.ResetBindings(false);
            //// dataGridView2.Refresh();
            
        }
```

SQL table output. [image] 
VB results before saving 
[image]
VB results after saving 
[image]

Comment: Your code seems ok.

Column1 and Column4 are populated in the database? According to the spec, the TableAdapter.GetData, it "Returns a new DataTable that's filled with data." Is the data correctly populated?

Comment: Hi Pedro, Yes its populated from database. As i mentioned its display column1,column2,column3,coolumn4 properly while first time opening. But saving new data its(col1,col14) disappears. attached database screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved. changing the adapter details to dataBindingSource5.DataSource = dataTableAdapter4.GetData();.

Thanks...